# Receiving a reply to a UDP packet

Tags: rust, network-programming

I am trying to receive a reply to a UDP packet. Sending the packet works and receiving replies to broadcasts works too. Receiving a reply to a packet sent to a specific IP, however, does not. I can see the reply being sent to the correct port in tcpdump and wireshark but somehow I can't seem to receive it in my program.

The following code sends a packet and should show me the replies to it but it does not print any replies.

```rust
println!("sending local");
let socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:2012").expect("could not create socket");
socket
    .connect(self.ip.unwrap())
    .expect("could not connect to ics");
socket.send(command).unwrap();
let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
while let Ok((n, addr)) = socket.recv_from(&mut buf) {
    println!("received {} bytes from {}", n, addr);
    buf.resize(n, 0);
}
```

Elsewhere in my program I use the following code to send a broadcast and listen to replies directed at my machine and this does work.

```rust
let command = create_discover_command();
let socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:2012").expect("Could not create socket");
socket.set_broadcast(true).expect("Could not set broadcast");
socket
    .set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::new(5, 0)))
    .expect("Could not set timeout");

match socket.send_to(&command, "255.255.255.255:2012") {
    Ok(n) => {
        if n != command.len() {
            println!("Error");
        }
    }
    Err(e) => {
        println!("Error: {}", e);
    }
}
let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
let mut address: Option<SocketAddr> = None;
while let Ok((n, addr)) = socket.recv_from(&mut buf) {
    println!("Received {} bytes from {}", n, addr);
    address = Some(addr);
    buf.resize(n, 0);
    match Message::try_from(buf.to_vec()) {
        Ok(mut message) => {
            if message.get_message_type() == MessageType::Acknowledge {
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
        Err(_e) => continue,
    }
}
```

I can't see any differences between these two functions apart from setting broadcast on the socket and the source port of the reply being sent. The destination port for both replies however is the same.

Comment: The code you provided runs just fine and can receive messages just fine too, of because I have to I'm assuming not both `UdpSockets` are used at the same time since it's impossible for 2 sockets to listen to the same address at the same time. i.e. you're not showing the part that actually produces the error.

Comment: @cafce25 the snippets are of two separate functions in my code so the sockets are indeed not used at the same time. The first function for me does not show any errors but rather seems to hang after printing "sending local"(probably hanging in the while loop). The only difference I can see is the source port of the reply between the two packets. The working broadcast one has the same source as destination(2012) while the other has a different(seemingly random) source port and 2012 as destination port.

Comment: Well as I said [your code works and receives messages for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0eb1b7d7fc5d387e8df1b4f286789ba4) so you'll have to provide more details.

Comment: Your code works for me locally too. When I look in wireshark I can see an icmp message from my machine to the sender saying Destination unreachable(port unreachable). The only thing I can see is that the source port from the reply is different than the source port of my message
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.63, Dst: 192.168.1.178
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 60770, Dst Port: 2012

Answer (score 0):

It seems that connecting to an ip and port using a udp socket in rust will only listen to replies from that specific ip and port. To prevent this from happening I changed my code to not connect to a specific ip but to use the send_to function like this.

```rust
let socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:2012").expect("could not create socket");
socket.send_to(command, self.ip.unwrap()).unwrap();
```

Comment: "It seems that connecting to an ip and port using a udp socket in rust will only listen to replies from that specific ip and port" yes, and for reference that fact is documented in the [documentation on `UdpSocket::connect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.connect): "and also applies filters to only receive data from the specified address."

Comment: Note that this is not specific to Rust. POSIX sockets behave the same way: _If the socket `sockfd` is of type `SOCK_DGRAM`_ (i.e. UDP), _then `addr` is_ […] _the only address from which datagrams are received._ ([source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html)).

Comment: And also note that this is what UDP `connect()` is *for.* It has no other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

[Jordys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75716952/442760) pretty much covers what the issue was, I found another solution that also works if you still want to use `connect` but still need to listen to any source you can 'disconnect' again by 'connecting' to `"0:0"` (`"[::]:0"` for IPv6):

```rust
println!("sending local");
let socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:2012").expect("could not create socket");
socket
    .connect(self.ip.unwrap())
    .expect("could not connect to ics");
socket.send(command).unwrap();
socket.connect("0:0").unwrap();
let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
while let Ok((n, addr)) = socket.recv_from(&mut buf) {
    println!("received {} bytes from {}", n, addr);
    buf.resize(n, 0);
}
```